# Issues with Windows Authentication on .Net 7 razor pages

Tags: c#, razor-pages, windows-authentication, .net-7.0

I have a razor page site where I need to use Windows Authentication to verify if a user is an admin. The issue I am getting is the authentication is looking at the logged in account on VS and not the logged in user on the actual computer. I have all the boxes checked correctly. I published my account thinking this would solve it but it grabs the service account and not the windows user.

Has anyone else had this issue? It has me completely stumped.

From my startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}

```
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting(); // Add this line to include the EndpointRoutingMiddleware

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });


        //Connection to the AMANDA DB
        services.AddDbContext<AmandaDBContext>(options =>
            options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Amanda")));

        var emailConfig = Configuration.GetSection("Email");

        services.AddFluentEmail(emailConfig.GetValue<string>("FromEmail"),                    `

 emailConfig.GetValue<string>("FromName"))
             .AddRazorRenderer()
             .AddSmtpSender(emailConfig.GetValue<string>("SmtpServer"),         emailConfig.GetValue<int>("SmtpPort"));
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddScoped<AuthorizationHelper>();
        services.AddScoped<PDFManager>();

    }
```

This is where the authorization checks if valid but it is getting the user from VS and not from Windows:
public bool IsUserAuthorized()
{
try
{
var windowsIdentity = Environment.UserName;

```
            string username = windowsIdentity;
            int i = username.LastIndexOf("\\", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (i >= 0)
            {
                username = username.Substring(i + 1);
            }

            var dbUser = _folderDB.Users.Where(u => u.Active && u.UserName.ToLower() == username.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();

            return dbUser != null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See this link for help: https://damienbod.com/2021/04/26/securing-an-asp-net-core-app-and-web-api-using-windows-authentication/. I believe windowsIdentity should be User.Identity.Name.